# Проверка правильности sourcemaps

Tags: веб-программирование, gulp, sourcemap

Структура моего проекта такая: (все папки описывань не буду, т.к. они здесь не причем)

- src
- scss

  - *.scss
- ts
- *.ts

Я пользуюсь gulp-sourcemaps

Вот файл для сборки css

```
const { src, dest } = require('gulp')
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'))
const concat = require('gulp-concat')
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps')
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer')

module.exports = function scss() {
    return src([
        'src/scss/style.scss',
        'src/scss/box.scss',
        'src/scss/dashboard.scss',
        'src/scss/sweetalert-custom.scss',
    ])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(
            autoprefixer({
                cascade: false,
            })
        )
        .pipe(concat('style.min.css'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(dest('build/css'))
}
```

И такой результат sourcemaps в DevTools:

[image: фото]

Все так и должно быть?

Comment: ...а что не так?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, просто мне кажется что папка должна была называтся ts, и ще должна быть папка js, в которой лежит скомпилированый файл main.min.js

То все правильно значит?